# Dump a Python dictionary with array value inside to CSV

Tags: python

I got something like this:

```
dict = {}
dict["p1"] = [.1,.2,.3,.4]
dict["p2"] = [.4,.3,.2,.1]
dict["p3"] = [.5,.6,.7,.8]
```

How I can dump this dictionary into csv like this structure? :

```
.1 .4 .5
.2 .3 .6
.3 .2 .7
.4 .1 .8
```

Really appreciated !

Comment: Did you have tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried for key, val in result.items():
    csv_writer.writerow([key,val]), however the data structure is not I want ..

Comment: Pleas add your code to question!

Comment: Python ``dict``(s) have no defined order. You'll need to use ``collections.OrderedDict`` here to preserve the order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dict`s have no order so you would need an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and to transpose the values:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
d["p1"] = [.1,.2,.3,.4]
d["p2"] = [.4,.3,.2,.1]
d["p3"] = [.5,.6,.7,.8]

with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(list(d))
    wr.writerows(zip(*d.values()))
```

Output:

```
p1,p2,p3
0.1,0.4,0.5
0.2,0.3,0.6
0.3,0.2,0.7
0.4,0.1,0.8
```

Also best to avoid shadowing builtin functions names like [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Comment: amazing , works so good, after 5 mins later I will approve it .

Comment: I raelly like the use of ``zip()`` here to "pivot" the data! Nice!

Comment: @BhargavRao, indeed, added.

Comment: Now it looks even better :P

Answer (score 3):

Basically the same thing but without using the `csv` module:

```
from __future__ import print_function


from collections import OrderedDict


data = OrderedDict()
data["p1"] = [.1, .2, .3, .4]
data["p2"] = [.4, .3, .2, .1]
data["p3"] = [.5, .6, .7, .8]

print(",".join(data.keys()))
print("\n".join(",".join(map(str, x)) for x in zip(*data.values())))
```

Output:

```
$ python -i foo.py
p1,p2,p3
0.1,0.4,0.5
0.2,0.3,0.6
0.3,0.2,0.7
0.4,0.1,0.8
>>>
```